# python requests module get method followed by json method getting stuck.

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am facing an issue with '**requests**' module of python.

I have these three lines of code:

```
print '\n\nTrying to fetch Tweets from URL %s' % url
newTweets = requests.get(url).json()
print 'Fetched %d tweets from URL: %s' % (len(newTweets), url)
```

And somehow the program execution gets **stuck** (program halts) on the second line. The 'url' parameter is a valid url to our backend server which serves '**valid**' json.

I have just started to experience this issue today. There are no loops in the code, so there's no scope for infinite looping. However, I still don't know what exactly happens inside '**get**' and '**json**' methods of requests module.

If anyone have any explanation for this, kindly reply.

Comment: What if you remove the inlined `.json()` call and just try to do the `get` by itself first?

Comment: If it's only recently started happening, then maybe twitter, or whatever API part of it you're using, is broken.

Comment: @Aya, but what can be broken? And why aren't there exceptional handlers within json() and get() methods to handle these exceptional cases. Moreover, our standard mechanism for data exchange is json, we abstract twitter completely at this level.

Comment: @VaidAbhishek Well, it might be dropping your packets, or the server might just be really slow. Does it work if you enter the URL into a web browser?

Comment: yes the url in browser does work.

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't answered @sberry? His is the question you should be answering. Also, I'm aware of several projects having issues with Twitter's v1 API. You should be moving to v1.1 since v1's EOL is sometime in June.

Answer (score 0):

Split your program into several steps

```
newTweets = requests.get(url)
```

then check status code for whatever you expect to return, e.g.:

```
if newTweets.status_code != 200:
     # exception handling

return newTweets.json()
```